# No login prompt for a TFS project in visual studio 2010

Tags: tfs, credentials, tfs-2010

In visual studio 2010, I added a solution to TFS 2010 using 'xx' credentials.
I closed visual studio IDE and opened the solution. this time, it didn't prompt me for the credentials. 
I would like to add one more solution to TFS using other credentials. By default, its taking old credentials. How can I change credentials

Answer (score 1):

Your credentials are stored in the credential manager: http://techrena.net/windows-7-credential-manager/